# how to create a different workspace in eclipse for different users?

Tags: linux, eclipse, workspace

I'm using Eclipse IDE for PHP Develoeprs Version 1.3.2 on Linux OS.

There are two different users called user_one and user_two

I've created a workspace for user_one by logging in with user_one credentials.

**I'm using TFS plugin for Eclipse to connects with TFS Server**

Now, I need to create a different workspace for user_two using user_two credentials.

When I try to do that I'm getting an error message

> "The new working folder mapping with "Current path" conflicts with the
>   existing mapping "user_one workspace path" "

My question is how do I create a different workspace for different users ?

Any help will be thankful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to create two different workspaces using same local folder mapping. You can create multiple workspaces by specifying different local folders mapping.